# Using Python to determine who can view/work outages from a csv and import the correct names into a new csv with proper fields

Tags: python, csv, text

I am trying to determine who can view and/or work outages based on a csv file. It doesn't have proper fields.  I want to take the appropriate users and place them into a new csv with proper fields. ["user", "view", "work", "district"]

My original document has the info laid out as follows:

Human Name: 
Disspatch Employee Name: 
Disspatch Crew Name: John Doe

Human Name: 
Disspatch Employee Name: 
Disspatch Crew Name: John Wick

Human Name: 
Disspatch Employee Name: Little John 
Disspatch Crew Name:

All of the data is in the A column.

I am very new to Python. I have imported csv, opened my orignial csv, made a list out of the data, and printed the rows just to see the results.

I have opened my new file and have successfully created the field headers that i need.

```
import csv

f = open("C:\\Python\\users.csv")
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
    print(row)

f.close()

NewFile = open("C:\\Python\\OutageUsers.csv", "w")
writer= csv.DictWriter(
    NewFile, fieldnames=["user", "view", "work", "district"])
writer.writeheader()
NewFile.close()
```

I don't have any errors with my current code, it just isn't complete.  I am unsure how to proceed from here.  Most examples I see online already have the input data in lovely fields, so it is easy to select your desired info. My original document is huge, so i really don't want to rearrange it.  Also, i have no guarantee that it won't be exactly the same if a newer copy is sent to me in the future. I need to figure out how to work with this format.  I appreciate any help or advice or a point in the right direction.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example pic of my org document:

[original csv pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQD3c.png)